# How do I center isotope and order its elements?

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

First of all, I've been looking for an answer on some similar asked questions before I made this one but none was helpful enough. I'm having difficulties centering isotope on my project without creating extra space between its elements and also I'm unable to order its elements (like the one with 300x460 dimensions) as shown in the screenshots below. I have tried to move it to the center with margin-left but it would stick the elements with each other.

[My current work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLVSL.png)

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwR79.png)

Here's my work on html and css so far:

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="portfolio-gallery">
            <div class="row grid">
                <div class="col-md-3 grid-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x260.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 grid-item grid-item--width2">
                    <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x220.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 grid-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x310.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 grid-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x200.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 grid-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x460.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 grid-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x370.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 grid-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x200.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.portfolio{
    padding-top: 64px;
    padding-bottom: 77px;
}
.portfolio .portfolio-gallery{
    margin: 60px auto;
}
.portfolio .grid-item{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve it using bootstrap or without bootstrap?

Comment: You should also include a bootstrap tag and specify where or not you are using bootstrap 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use bootstrap classes in your isotope elements. Also, the ordering question doesn't make too much sense for me. It's in the nature of Isotope to reorder it's elements with every resize, the rules depending on layout mode. Sorting makes sense when you have elements with equal dimensions, like in the sorting demo (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html).

**Here a codepen with Isotope, building the combination of tiles from your image:
https://codepen.io/Sixl/full/GMaQre/**

Maybe it is somehow of help to you?

**CSS:**

```
.grid {
  background-color: #none;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 10px auto;
    &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    }
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #bada55;
  color: white;
  font-size: 96px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  &--220 { height: 220px;}
  &--260 { height: 260px;}
  &--310 { height: 310px;}
  &--370 { height: 370px;}
  &--460 { height: 460px;}
}
```

**JS:**

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'packery',
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--260">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--220">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--310">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--460">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--200">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--370">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--200">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pictures - like text goes under each other, so your picture order is not OK.
Plus I needed to add "make 3 columns" in css.
...and "go columns next to each other"... and cleared a bit.

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-gallery">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x260.png">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x200.png">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x200.png">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
           <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x220.png">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x460.png">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x310.png">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="assets/images/placeholdit300x370.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.portfolio{
    padding-top: 64px;
    padding-bottom: 77px;
    float: left;
    column-count: 3;
}
.portfolio .grid-item{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}`
```